# Change default text editor to Sublime Text in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, text-editors, file-association, sublime-text-3

I've installed Sublime Text 3 from the .deb found here: http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Now, how to set it as the default text editor in place of gedit in Mint 16?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` in Sublime:

```
sudo subl /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Search for all instances of `gedit` and replace them with `sublime_text`. Save the file, quit Sublime, log out and back in, and you should be all set.

***EDIT***

While the above instructions should work with any `.deb`-based system (I use Ubuntu), apparently there is an issue with Mint where changes to `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` are lost upon reboot. To work around this, do the following:

1. Create a new file (if it doesn't already exist) called `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` in Sublime. The first line should be `[Default Applications]`.
2. Open `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` in Sublime. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to open the **`Find`** dialog and type ***`gedit`*** into the search box.
3. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the **<kbd>`Find All`</kbd>** button to select all the instances of `gedit` in the file.
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to expand the selections to the entire line, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the lines.
5. In `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the lines containing `gedit`.
6. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to open the **`Replace`** dialog. Search for `gedit` and replace with `sublime_text`. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to Replace All (or click the **<kbd>`Replace All`</kbd>** button) and you're all set.
7. Save `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`, log out and back in, and Sublime Text should now be your default text editor.

Comment: It works at first, but after rebooting, defaults.list gets reverted, gedit back in place of sublime_text. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Apparently this is [an issue with Mint](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=defaults.list+reboot+site:forums.linuxmint.com) which can be circumvented by using `.local/share/applications/defaults.list` instead. So, I've copied/pasted/edited the gedit lines to this file, and they're now successfully overriding their counterparts in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`, even after a reboot.

Comment: @xichael - thanks for the info. I've updated my answer to describe exactly how to set things up to work around this issue. I usually use Ubuntu, where my original solution works fine, and since Mint is quite similar I figured it would work!

Comment: You're missing a small step: the first line on ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list must be "[Default Applications]" for this to work

Comment: @Alexandre thanks for that, I'll update the answer. As an Ubuntu user, I've only worked with existing files, so I kinda missed that detail :)

Comment: @MattDMo, no need to run Sublime Text as sudo `sudo subl /usr/...` Sublime Text prompts you for the sudo password when you attempt to save a the root file. Anyways, should not it be `gksudo` for applications?

Answer (score 4):

so I just figured out a less complicated way to do it.

Step 1:
Select any file that you want to open with Sublime. Right-click on it.

Step 2:
Go to Properties.

Step 3:
Go to Open With

Step 4:
Select Sublime

Step 5:
Set as Default

Comment: The accepted answer should be this.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to edit system files yourself, you can simply go to "Preferred applications" in settings.

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer worked for me too, many thanks for the clear instructions!

Just to state the obvious, in case it helps someone: if you want a different default editor, then:

- ensure it's executable name, eg `vim` replaces `gedit` in the ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list file
- ensure `export EDITOR=path\executable` is included in the appropriate config file for you (`~\.profile` or `~\.bashrc` or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command:

```
$ xdg-mime default sublime-text_subl.desktop text/plain
```

where "sublime-text_subl.desktop" is your desktop app. Change it if it is another name.